# How do I overload the + operator to add multiple variables to an array in one line

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I am overloading the + operator in C++ to add numbers to an array. I can't add more than one number to the array in one line of code.

This is my + operator method

```
template<typename Item>
SortedCollection<Item> SortedCollection<Item>::operator+(Item num){
  SortedCollection<Item> a;
  this -> add(num);
  return a;
 }
```

This is the add method in the class it inherits from

```
template<typename Item>
void Collection<Item>::add(Item e) {
    if (curSize == capacity) {
      expand();
    }
    elements[curSize] = e;
    curSize++;
}
```

```
SortedCollection<int> one;
 one + 19 + 9 + 2 + 8 + 7 + 12  + 17 + 0 + 11 + 6 + 3 + 1;
 cout << one[0] << endl;
 cout << one[1] << endl;
```

In main, the output of this is
19
0
However when I try

```
one + 19;
one + 9;
cout << one[0] << endl;
cout << one[1] << endl;
```

It works like intended
19
9
If anyone knows how I can get it to all add on the same line I would appreciate it.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ how to overload operator+".

Answer (score 1):

`+` is not best choice for such operation. According to principle of "least surprise" `+` should not modify its operands. Better to use `<<` for example.

That being said you have couple of problems:

1. Operator should return reference to object, not copy of object.
2. There is no need to create `a` object, just return `*this`.